# What's the point of aclocal?

Tags: autotools

What's the point of the **aclocal** script and **aclocal.m4** file, in context of using autotools to configure source files? From what I read, aclocal scans macro files for macros that are later used by automake. I don't understand this process in depth, but it seems that the scanning functionality could have just been embedded into automake.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, can you explain the "m4sh" and "m4sugar" tags, please?  What are they and how do they apply to this question, when they aren't mentioned anywhere in the question or answers?

Comment: @Charles autoconf does not directly use m4, rather it uses the wrappers `m4sh` and `m4sugar`.  The purpose of aclocal is to make m4sh and m4sugar macros available to autoconf.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, the problem here is that the question is not ultimately about `m4sh` or `m4sugar`, but about `aclocal` and autotools in general.  I see nothing here, or in the other question you tagged with those two tags, that actually makes the tags relevant to the question.

Comment: @Charles, in that case, the `m4` tag should also be removed.  `m4sh` is more relevant than `m4`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

See [Alexandre Duret Lutz's Autotools tutorial](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html), a must read.

It contains diagrams explaining how the different files of an autotools project interact with each other and by which tool they are used: `configure`, `config.h`, `config.status`, `aclocal.m4` etc

EDIT:
John Calcote also explains the purpose of aclocal and aclocal.m4 in the first chapter of [his book about Autotools](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool/): [Chapter 1: A brief introduction to the GNU Autotools](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/brief_introduction_to_gnu_autotools/):

> The aclocal utility is actually documented by the GNU manuals as a temporary work-around for a certain lack of flexibility in Autoconf. Autoconf was designed and written first, and then a few years later, the idea for Automake was conceived as an add-on for Autoconf. But Autoconf was really not designed to be extensible on the scale required by Automake.

...

> Essentially, aclocal’s job is to create an aclocal.m4 file by consolidating various macro files from installed Autotool packages and user-specified locations, such that Autoconf can find them all in one place.

...

> However, the latest documentation from both sets of tools suggests that the entire aclocal/acinclude paradigm is now obsolete, in favor of a newer method of specifying a directory containing m4 macro files. The current recommendation is that you create a directory in your project directory called simply m4 (acinclude seems more appropriate to this author), and add macros in the form of individual .m4 files to this directory. All files in this directory will be gathered into aclocal.m4 before Autoconf processes your configure.ac file. Ultimately, aclocal will be replaced by functionality in Autoconf itself.

Comment: So, had `aclocal` got replaced by Autoconf functionality?

Comment: I don't believe it did

Answer (score 12):

In my software, `aclocal.m4` collects the various non-standard Autoconf macros that I use during the builds of my software.  One such set of macros deals with sub-second timing - choosing the best of the available options (according to some pre-determined criterion for what is 'best'); another such set of macros deals with the intricacies of the IBM Informix ESQL/C compilation system as it has evolved over the last two decades (it handles ESQL/C 5.20, where version 5.00 was released in 1990, and it also handles the latest versions of IBM Informix ClientSDK 3.50 - which, much to my chagrin, contains ESQL/C 3.50 even though it was released in 2008).

So, `aclocal.m4` is for local macros that are not necessarily part of regular Autoconf but which are used by your specific software.

Comment: +1, that's exactly what its for. A lot of people just drop those bits in configure.ac / configure.in which has been known to cause madness, blindness and even tourette syndrome for distribution maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

The link to John Calcote's article as given by http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/brief_introduction_to_gnu_autotools/.  I would have commented on that post but my reputation here is too low.

The essential paragraph:

Essentially, aclocal's job is to create an aclocal.m4 file by consolidating various macro files from installed Autotool packages and user-specified locations, such that Autoconf can find them all in one place.